# How to plot integration equation using Python?

Tags: python, integral

I have a few of integration equations and need to convert it into Python. The problem is when I tried to plot a graph according to the equation, some of the plot is not same with the original one.

The first equation is the error probability of authentication in normal operation:
[image]

The second equation is the error probability of authentication under MIM attack:

[image]

The error probability can be calculated by:

[image]

It is noted that:
[image]

Supposedly, the graph **(original)** will be shown like this:

[image]

Pe^normal = blue lines

Pe^MIM = red lines

Differences between two error probabilities = green lines

I tried to code it into Python and this is my full codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import iv,modstruve

x=np.arange(0.1,21,1)
x = np.array(x)
t = 0.9
y = (np.exp(t*x/2)*(iv(0, t*x/2) - modstruve(0,t*x/2))-1)/(np.exp(t*x)-1)
z = (np.exp((1-t**2)*x/2)*(iv(0, (1-t**2)*x/2) - modstruve(0,(1-t**2)*x/2))-1)/(np.exp((1-t**2)*x)-1)
z2= y+z


plt.plot(x, y,'o', color='red',label='Normal')
plt.plot(x, z2,  '-', color='black', label='MIM')
plt.plot(x, z,  marker='s', linestyle='--', color='g', label='DIFF')
plt.xlabel('Mean photon number N')
plt.ylabel('Error probabiity')
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.text(10, 0.4, 't=0.9', size=12, ha='center', va='center')
plt.ylim([0, 0.5])
plt.xlim([0, 20])
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The graph produce from the code is:
[image]

It looks like that my plot is not same with the original one in terms N=0 of Pe^MIM (red line) and differences between two error probabilities (green line).

I hope that anyone may help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a math issue. You did not show us a formula for `P^{Auth, MIM}`, also I note that you calculate the `diff` first and then get `P^{Auth, MIM}` from the diff. Is that a supposed method?

Comment: @ Konstantin Sekeresh. `P^{Auth, MIM}` was not given in this calculation.
For the `diff`, I just try & error to calculate it using the `P^{Auth, MIM}`, and I know maybe my calculation is wrong. Thus, I need clarification from others about this calculation.

Comment: @ Konstantin Sekeresh.It can be noted that the difference is `P^{Auth, MIM}`- `P^{Auth, normal}`.